# How to select last one week data from today's date

Tags: sql-server-2008, dateadd

How to select week data (more precisely, last 7 days data) from the current date in the fastest way as I have millions or rows in the table. I have a time stamp of created_date in sql table.

I have tried this

```
SELECT Created_Date
FROM Table_Name
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

I have two question:

1. Is this query is correct?
2. Is this is the fastest way to get the last seven day data from a table having millions of rows ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is accurate and it should be fine.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91029/3) I created for your particular case

```
create table sample2
(
    id int primary key,
    created_date date,
    data varchar(10)
  )

insert into sample2 values (1,'2012-01-01','testing');
```

And here is how to select the data

```
SELECT Created_Date
FROM sample2
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-11117, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 18):

to select records for the last 7 days

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName]
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

to select records for the current week

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Define beginning of week as Monday
SELECT * FROM [TableName]
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) 
  AND CreatedDate <  DATEADD(day, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

if you want to select records for last week instead of the last 7 days

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Define beginning of week as Monday
SELECT * FROM [TableName] 
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + 6), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) 
  AND CreatedDate <  DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The query is correct

2A. As far as last seven days have much less rows than whole table an index can help

2B. If you are interested only in Created_Date you can try using some group by and count, it should help with the result set size

Answer (score 0):

To select records for the last 7 days and last week from today's date:

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName]
WHERE created_date >= now() - interval '1 week'
```

Comment: "now" does not exist in Microsoft SQL